# Revert changes in code in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, back

I use Eclipse and I am looking for a plugin or something with which I can undo all changes made in the code in the folder/project to state before a specified time. Eclipse keeps local history, but only for individual files. The entire folder can not be reverted.

Comment: There's two popular change control products, Subversion and Git

Answer (score 0):

This is when you'd want to use a full source control system, like Git, Subversion, even CVS, etc., all of which have available plug-ins.

Comment: I'm using GIT already and I know that I can revert code to commit. But I don't want to make commit. It would be ideal if I could do something like snapshot, make changes in the code and see if it works well and then go back to the snapshot.